# Restore MSSQL .bak file to Centos MSSQL, but cannot use the backup file

Tags: sql-server, centos

i was trying to restore the mssql file inside the centos server. The .bak file already put inside the server and make the user as the mssql.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is the error when i run this command to restore.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DataDB] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'demodb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

After i enter this command, it show me this error.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

For this kind of the problem, how do i change the sector size through the centos ? Or must use the SQL explorer management.

```
[root@RAC data]# sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [DataDB] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
Password: 
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server RAC, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DataDB.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server RAC, Line 1
File 'DataDB' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DataDB.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Server RAC, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DataDB_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Server RAC, Line 1
File 'DataDB_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DataDB_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Server RAC, Line 1
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server RAC, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: Text should *really* be posted as what it is... `text`.

Comment: Considering, however, you are overwriting the backup file, have you considered deleting the file and trying again?

Comment: What you mean on the text? Not really understand . Ya, i tried on delete and upload to the server again, but it still show me the same result.

Comment: You posted text as images. Why are you putting the file there in the first place? You're backing up your database, you don't need the backup to be there already. If you're saving a new excel file you don't make sure the file already exists before hand.

Comment: Sorry, i must confuse, let me rephrase the question again.

Comment: So what *are* you doing; a `BACKUP` or `RESTORE`. They are very different operations... Your previous screenshot showed "`BACKUP`", but your posted text says "`RESTORE`". I feel like the issue may be you are confused with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Right now i am trying to do is to restore the .bak inside the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not why you're putting a copy of the back up on your server first, when what you're doing is backing it up; that makes no sense. If you were trying to `RESTORE` the database sure, but you're doing a `BACKUP`. Considering the problem is that the file you are trying to overwrite has a different sector format, I suggest deleting the file first and then backing up:

```
rm /var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak && sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [DataDB] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'demodb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak'  WITH FILE = 1

you need verify backup list.

RESTORE DATABASE dbane
FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/DataDB.bak''
WITH
MOVE 'logical name' TO '**linuxth**\dbname.mdf',
MOVE 'logicalname' TO '**linuxth**\DEMO_Winmedicare.ldf', recovery ;